# Access partial results of a Celery task

Tags: python, celery, jobs

I'm not a Python expert, however I'm trying to develop some long-running Celery-based tasks which I'm able to access their partial results instead of waiting for the tasks to finish.

As you can see in the code below, given a multiplier, an initial and final range, the *worker* creates a list of size *final_range - initial_range + 1*.

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('trackers', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def worker(value, initial_range, final_range):
    if initial_range < final_range
        list_values = []
        for index in range(initial_frame, final_frame + 1):
            list_values.append(value * index)
        return list_values
    else
        return None
```

So, instead of waiting for all *four workers* to finish, I would like to access the to-be-returned values (*list_values*) before they are actually returned.

```
from trackers import worker

res_1 = worker.delay(3, 10, 10000000)
res_2 = worker.delay(5, 01, 20000000)
res_3 = worker.delay(7, 20, 50000000)
res_4 = worker.delay(9, 55, 99999999)
```

First of all, is it possible? 
If so, what sort of changes do I have to perform to make it work?

Comment: Do you mean you want to access res_1 without waiting for res_4, or you want to access list_values before the jobs finish?

Comment: I want to access list_values before the jobs finish

Comment: Then you are going to need a source of truth that you can dump values into and read from.  If you are running on a single machine, this could be as easy as creating global data structures that the workers and the parent process can both access (though this is usually not a good idea- getting multi-threaded access to globals right is very hard).  A better solution is to use an external source of truth like a database.  I have used redis for things like this- the workers append values to the data structure, the parent reads it, and redis handles the threading and access issues.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBecotte, but how can I access (read/write) the source of truth from another task (running concurrently) or from the main method?

Comment: I actually haven't thought about it- the basic way of launching celery workers separates the processes pretty completely, which would make it impossible to share global variables.  However, you must have a transport set up for Celery to handle tasks, so using that to pass data back to the parent process should be pretty easy.

Comment: Why do you need to access partial results outside the task before the task is done?

Comment: @Louis I have to update the interface with the elements that have already been computed.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to use an external storage such as SQL or Redis/Memcached because different tasks can be executed on different servers in common case.

So in your example you should store list_values in some DB and update it during the loop.

Comment: I found out that Redis is some sort of main-memory DB (no need to access disk). Therefore, I would rather use Redis, I just don't know how to access the partial results outside the workers.

Comment: Redis is a good choice for this task. And each worker is a separate OS process so nobody outside can read his memory. For interprocess communication on the Linux can be used named pipes, shared memory(using tmpfs for example) and sockets and all these methods give way for Redis in your case, because it's easy to use and easy to scale.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you split the work performed in each task.

If you need the first values for computing the values later in the list, then you can chain the tasks via `link` parameter. See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#callbacks